# How can i hide tab in ngb-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to hide the ngb-tab. When i include the ngb-tab the title tab appears on my table head. Is there any way to hide the ngb-tab ??

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {faCaretLeft} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-book-container',
  templateUrl: './address-book-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-book-container.component.scss']
})
export class AddressBookContainerComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

---

**This is my html**

```
<div class="container mt-5 ">
    <div class="row">
      <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab >
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <app-address-book-table></app-address-book-table>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
      </ngb-tabset>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tabset is deprecated since version 6.0.0 and is not supported anymore. Use Nav directives

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *ngIf statement to hide it, I declared as "false" but you can put a variable boolean in order to change when is true or false.

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <ngb-tabset>
        <ngb-tab *ngIf="false">
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            <app-address-book-table></app-address-book-table>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-tab>
      </ngb-tabset>
    </div>
  </div>
```